# APIs: Do you need to send the authentication header token with every request?

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, flask-jwt-extended

I'm currently making an API and wanted to know if the API user has to send the token every time they make a request. I'm using Flask_JWT_Extended to handle authentication with the API. The token gets send in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's one of the consequences of the REST "stateless" constraint.

> each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request -- [Fielding 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)

Answer (score 0):

When you use JWT as authentication and authorization, yes - your consumer needs to send the token with every request to prove that he is authenticated.

The idea is:

- authenticate against a login service
- obtain a token
- use this token against multiple services which do not need to store/share a session

You can implement a session even with JWT and require your user to send a session cookie or similar - but doing so, you have the problem that you need to share the server-side session among different services, where JWT is a way to get rid of it.

Of course, the JWT token itself is larger in size than a simple cookie in many cases, but that should not be such a big deal nowadays.